# Почему не срабатывает .ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('#osForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: "http://oooenergy.ru/sendOrderForm.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {"email" : "kkk"},
  success: function(response) {
    //обработка успешной отправки
    alert('Купон придет на Ваш email в ближайшее время.')
  },
  error: function(response) {
    //обработка ошибок при отправке
alert('Купон придет на Ваш email в ближайшее время.');
 }
});
});

<form method="" name="osForm" action="" id="osForm" >   
<input class="osForm_input" tabindex="2" id="email" name="email" type="text"  />

<input class="osForm_btn button5 button5-blue" tabindex="4" type="submit" name="sndbtn" value="Получить купон"  />
</form>
```

Ни один из алертов не срабатывает. Почему?

Comment: Попробуйте `data: {'email':'k@k.ru'}`

Comment: Ну, вообще-то, у submit и function скобки не закрыты.

Comment: Ошибки в консоли какие? На сервере какие ошибки?

Comment: Ну так при чём тут ajax? Тут ошибка явно в скрипте PHP.

Comment: @Радик Камалов может вы расскажете, что конкретно не работает?  Не срабатывает функция $('#osForm').submit? Не срабатывает экшн на сервере? Ответ от сервера не попадает в success или в error? Или еще что-то? Отладчиком пройти пробовали? А браузер какие-либо ошибки выдает?

Comment: Конечно летит в error, если сервер отдает 301. А вы чего ожидали-то?

Comment: @Радик Камалов как вам сказали выше, ковыряйте php-код, это ошибка, происходящая на сервере. Телепатов тут нет, по фотографиям лечить умеют только всякие там кашпировские, поэтому вряд ли вам кто-то сможет сказать, в чем проблема, увидев только ваш клиентский код

Comment: Изменил путь к php-скрипту, начал отправлять. 

Возник другой вопрос, почему то не заходит ни в success, ни в error. Т.е. alert не срабатывает

Comment: @Радик Камалов между прочим, если у вас и в success и в error один  тот же код, логичнее использовать complete

>Изменил путь к php-скрипту, начал отправлять.
Возник другой вопрос, почему то не заходит ни в success, ни в error

а вы отладчиком вообще пользуетесь? Или это не путь самурая?

Comment: Так откуда еще я мог узнать, что не заходит в success , если не с отладчика?

Comment: я говорю не только про клиент, но и про сервер

Comment: А вы на тот же домен отправляете, на каком сайт? Просто тут ещё политика безопасности, даже вроде на поддомены нельзя.

Comment: у меня тоже самое. отсылаю форму, сервер принимает, обратно жосон возвращается, статус 200. но сукес не срабатывает.

Comment: eri, редирект проверь. отправляешь с www или без www